With Gravity Forms, how do I make the gAppointments add on availability period 24 hours instead of 1 day?
I am working with Gravity Forms to create an appointment booking system using gAppointments addon. The challenge I am facing is that I need to make the availability period in each of the services 24 hours instead of 1 day.
gAppointments by default only allows the availability period to be 1 day or more which allows all the time slots available the next day to be shown. I need the time slots to only open 24 hours in advance and not before that.
So is there a way I can achieve this functionality via custom code or plugin?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.
